# How can I move a field from one model to another, and still retain the data?

Tags: python, django, django-models

To simplify, I have a model, say,

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

and another model that holds an image field, that ties itself to a parent instance via foreign key:

```
class ParentPicture(models.model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The original plan was to support multiple pictures for the parent, and only have one in use at any one time, but now, I'd like to have support for just one picture, and include it in the parent model, so that `ParentPicture` can be destroyed, and have `Parent` look like so:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
```

I'm unsure of the best way to move the `picture` field over to the new model, and include the instances from the `ParentPicture` that have the `is_used` flag.

Is there a simple way to do this automatically with Django, or would I need to make the change to the `Parent` model, migrate the change, then run a script to go through the `ParentPicture` model and copy appropriately, and then *only* after that's been done, remove the `ParentPicture` model?

Thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: You would have to do the latter, unfortunately. The middle step can be done as a migration as well though - see the docs on [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think there is not an 'automatic' way to move the field, so you could do:

1. Add `picture` field to `Parent` class
2. Generate and run a schema migration
3. Write and run a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to populate the new `picture` field with values in the model `ParentPicture`
4. Delete old/obsolete models/fields, generate a new schema migration and run it

Comment: I had no idea that you could run such scripts inside a migration. Extremely helpful thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is a multistep process. First you need to add the fields to as follows and then do ./manage.py makemigrations

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=40)    
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

For the second step you have two options. The first is to create a migrations.RunPython that queries the ParentPicture table and updates the Parent table with the values from it. This wouldn't involve in raw sql but it would be inefficient. On the other hand if you have only a few rows it wouldn't matter.

```
  for p in ParentPicture.objects.all():
      Parent.objects.filter(pk = p.parent_id
           ).update(picture=p.picture, is_used=p.is_used)
```

The alternative is to use a `migrations.RunSQL` with an `UPDATE JOIN` type of query. This will be efficient and recommended if you have a large number of records. In mysql your query might look like this:

```
UPDATE app_parent p 
   INNER JOIN app_parentpicture pp on
      p.id = pp.parent_id
   SET p.picture = pp.picture, 
      p.is_used = pp.is_used
```

Step 3, do you really need to drop the old table at this stage? Why not wait until some thorough testing has been done?

Comment: I was looking for ways to migrate data, but now I'm considering leaving the old data in place and working with the new data. Step 3 might just be the best idea for my situation. Great question!