# Can Django create a default row in a new table for each row in an existing table?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a company table populated with data. The need to introduce branches table has arisen. What mechanic would be used in Django to use the existing data in the company table to create a basic branch entry for each of the existing company entries.

"Company A will get a default HQ branch as part of the migration."

Is there a way to tie a function to the migration or would I need to create a custom migration that performs the operation after the table creation procedure is handled?

#### models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

# This is the new model/table
# Each Company must have at least one branch post migration
class Branch(models.Model):
    branch_id = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name="Branch ID",
        null=False,
        default=1000),
    parent_branch = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: can you share some code regarding this?

Comment: Done! I added my models.py. I realize I can two step this migration where I introduce the new table, write a one time script to populate the branch table, but I would a feature mechanic like this exists in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found the answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171077/how-can-i-move-a-field-from-one-model-to-another-and-still-retain-the-data) Performing it as two separate operations where I create the new table without altering the old one, performing the data migration, then deploying the new code that runs off of it.